# How to replace fixlength alphanumeric character?

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace String after alphanumeric of fix length only using sed.

```
testing-1xs-a-2x-782b1x9.abc.txt
testing-12a-b-2y-486eee2.bcd.txt
testing-1a-c-2z-b62cx7d.cde.txt
```

I tried this command - `sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}.*//g'` file

Expected output :

```
testing-1xs-a-2x
testing-12a-b-2y
testing-1a-c-2z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk --re-interval '{sub(/-[[:alnum:]]{7}.*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

In case your `awk` is of new version you could remove `--re-interval` from above code.

In `sed` you could try following.

```
sed -E 's/-[[:alnum:]]{7}.*//'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/-[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}.*//g' ip.txt
testing-1xs-a-2x
testing-12a-b-2y
testing-1a-c-2z
```

- `{}` are not special in default BRE, so use `-E` switch to enable ERE (some versions require `-r` instead of `-E`)
- added missing `-` at start of regex

For given sample, you could also use these, but perhaps may not suit your real use-case.. some more details about the nature of data would help in deciding which one to use

```
$ sed 's/-[^-]*$//' ip.txt
testing-1xs-a-2x
testing-12a-b-2y
testing-1a-c-2z

$ cut -d- -f1-4 ip.txt
testing-1xs-a-2x
testing-12a-b-2y
testing-1a-c-2z
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, let say if there is another line like `testing-1aasdfa-c-2z-b62cx7d.cde.txt` then how can we avoid the first alphanumeric and get the output like `testing-1aasdfa-c-2z` for fourth line. Let me know I need to post it in as new question. I tried this "sed -E 's/-[[:alnum:]]{7}.*//2g' file" but didn't succeed.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR for that sample, both `sed 's/-[^-]*$//'` and `cut -d- -f1-4` will work