# How to ignore 1st occurence of alphanumeric and replace everything after 2nd occurence?

Tags: sed

This is a followup question on an existing question - 
[How to replace fixlength alphanumeric character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750693/how-to-replace-fixlength-alphanumeric-character), 
There are two use cases -

> a. Remove everything from where 2nd alphanumeric in a line start, if
>   it contain two alnum of size 7.
>
> b. Remove everything from where 1st alphanumeric in a line start, if
>   it contain only one alnum of size 7.

```
testing-1xs-a-2x-782b1x9.abc.txt
testing-12a-b-2y-486eee2.bcd.txt
testing-1a-c-2z-b62cx7d.cde.txt
testing-1aasdfa-c-2z-b62cx7d.cde.txt
```

I tried this command - `sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}.*//2g' file`

Expected output :

```
testing-1xs-a-2x
testing-12a-b-2y
testing-1a-c-2z
testing-1aasdfa-c-2z
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What exactly are the first and second *alphanumeric* characters you are looking for? In your example, the first is `t` and the second is `e`. Do you mean *numeric* characters?

Comment: Your 2nd field `12a` is also alphanumeric right, then why it is not removed from your expected output please explain more on this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @RavinderSingh13 but the catch is - alnum of length 7.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, so means 2nd occurrence of 7 letters of alnum right? Because your expected output don't justify that.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thanks for checking on this and I don't see any doubt in question, if line has two alnum{7} then remove from 2nd alnum (of length 7) from where it start if it contain only one alnum then remove from 1st alnum(of length 7), ignore any alnum which is length < 7.
 Point Out exact doubt if it is not clear yet, I will try to explain.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, after your update of questions, it is clear now thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/-?\w{7}([-.]\w{1,6}\b)*//2g' file
```

Remove an optional `-` followed by a 7 character word, followed by zero or more words between 1 and 6 characters long preceded by a `.` or a `-`.

N.B. The last line of the test data will  be just `testing` as `2g` means 2 or more in GNU sed.